# Had to refresh my Windows, programs are not registered now

Tags: windows-8.1, refresh

So prior to the refresh, I had partitioned my hard drive. All my important programs I kept on a separate drive from Windows 8.1. For whatever reason, my computer stopped working and so I had to refresh my Windows. Now, everything is back to factory settings on my C:/ . The thing is all my programs that I use are still on my D:/ but they do not appear in the add/remove programs function in the control panel; Windows does not seem to detect them. I can still open them, but I don't seem to be activated/registered to Windows, thus they are stuck in demo mode.

My question is, can I register/activate these programs so they can be detected by Windows now, or will I have to format my computer and start from scratch?

Comment: You should reinstall the programs that are on drive d:

Comment: When you perform a Refresh on Windows 8.1 you must reinstall ALL applications, the fact they were on another drive, does not matter.

Answer (score 0):

Unless your software on the D:\ Drive is considered a Portable application there are no garantees that the software will work correctly again without a re-install.

When you install software the location is not the only important part. Registry keys and other files are still added to your system for a multitude of reasons. especially licences.

When you refreshed/reinstalled Windows, you've reset these files and the registry and therefore Windows does not have any association with them.

In order to fix this, you will un-doubtably have to either revert to a system backup image OR re-run the installer for each program, possibly re-supplying the licence keys.